# Advantages and disadvantages of installing a LAMP using lamp-server^ package vs individual Apache, PHP, MySQL installation

Tags: php, mysql, apache, lamp

I want to setup LAMP in Azure server, There are approachs to setup LAMP using below methods

1. LAMP Package : `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`
2. Apache, PHP, MySQL individual installation

   `sudo apt-get install apache2`

   `sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt`

   `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

**Questions :**

How upgrading can be handled in the future, If I install LAMP using first approach?

Advantages and disadvantages of the above approaches and can suggest the best way to set up LAMP?

Comment: This is a great question for quora dot com. Check them out.

Comment: @Drew can you give me the link of Quora post ?

Answer (score 0):

The first one is easier if someone needs a fast and easy solution.

For proper setup and long term project, I would prefer to do the 2nd method.

As I searched for `apt-get install lamp-server` there are a few disadvantages:

- This approach is that the application files are not placed in the file system in a standard way, which can cause confusion.
- When a new version is released, the same process used to install the application is needed to apply updates.
- As I am in control of what is being installed when to install and keep track of my installation.
- Skip software I don't need.